# Firebase auth anonymous in Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate Firebase backend to my app.

Created my podfile with

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

Everything looks fine with the sdk import

In my first view controller I do:

```
    import Firebase

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")
ref.authAnonymouslyWithCompletionBlock { error, authData in
          if error != nil {
             // There was an error logging in anonymously
          } else {
             // We are now logged in
          }
        }
     }
```

But i got an `Can not call value of non-function type error`

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of firebase you are using????

Comment: in podfile i didn't mention about that

Comment: so latest one right ... than https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 thanks for the link, i think every definition has changed

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 after using parse.com, it is a torture

Comment: LOL .. may be you are right .. but I am not as I am working with firebase from a month or two :)

Answer (score 0):

So they have changed the way you install Firebase with pods, Now instead of just adding pod 'Firebase' you must add the individual pods like this.

```
use_frameworks!

   target “Your Project” do
     pod 'Firebase/Core’
     pod 'Firebase/Database’
     pod 'Firebase/Auth’
end
```

However, you only need to put 'import Firebase' and it will cover all pods relating to Firebase. And don't forget to configure Firebase in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of your AppDelegate!

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

Good Luck!!